# How to delete a selection with straight edges in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I have an issue deleting selected area in Photoshop.

I use pen tool -> make a selection -> set 0px feather, +anti-alias ->
And I have a result like below:

[image]

Am I missing something to get straight and accurate edges ?
Maybe that's relative to some sort of pixels snaping?

UPD. Without anti-alias:
[image]

Comment: Maybe yout looking for a clipping mask? wont look beter in PS but will when exported. And yes this.is how it should work.

Answer (score 6):

This is called anti-aliasing and yields a better, smoother result when you zoom back out. If you don't want those half-transparent pixels, you should deactivate the anti-aliasing option when selecting.

Exactly straight edges are only possible in Photoshop when those edges are exactly horizontal or exactly vertical (or *maybe* if exactly 45°). The nature of a pixel image is a raster of square pixels, so any slope needs to be simulated with anti-aliasing like this.

Comment: Thanks... But I couldn't believe I get correct result (with or without anti-alias). The edges are way too rough...

Comment: Then your image is of a too low resolution--too little pixels on too big an area. Billy Kerr has some good tips for you in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are missing something - a piece of crucial information.

Photoshop is a raster image editor - and all raster images are made of pixels, and if you zoom in on the pixels, then you will see them.

Your first image shows what anti-aliasing looks like when zoomed in.

Your second image shows what it looks like when you don't use anti-aliasing.

All of this is perfectly normal, and everything is working perfectly as it should.  There are no problems here at all.

To see the image as it will appear in reality, or in a browser etc, set the zoom level to 100% in Photoshop.

Comment: I am sure I miss some crucial information.
But the 2nd image was at Ctrl+0 and at 100% this rough gradation is visible as well...

Comment: @Olenia If you have no anti-aliasing, the edge will look jagged at 100% unless it's at 45 degrees exactly. This is normal. There is nothing wrong!